# Optimal way of defining constants in a python function

Tags: python, functional-programming

this might be a more theoretic question than a practical one, as it does not make a significant difference in the runtime of the program. At least not in my case.

I have received some python code which imports different ("homemade") functions. One function (call it **func**) is called 5 times from the main script (call it **main**).

In **func** a lot of constants are defined in the beginning of the function. For example:

```
    import numpy as np
    def func(x,y,z):
        c0 = np.array([1,2,3])
        c1 = np.array([1,2,3])
        c2 = np.array([1,2,3])
        c3 = np.array([1,2,3])

        #do stuff with variables x,y,z
        #return stuff
```

I was wondering: When calling this function, are the constants c0,...,c3 defined each time the function is called, or is it "fixed" when it is compiled to bytecode when running the **main** script, so that they are only defined once?

Comment: Defining an array inside func is probably not a very big performance issue, and semantically, if it's the only function using them, it's arguable they should stay there. However, importing numpy inside the function look bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are defined each time the function is called.

The dynamic nature of Python means that the value of `np.array` may have changed in the time between the function's definition and its call (and betweeen calls), so the compiler has no opportunity to evaluate them "in advance".

If you save them in a closure, you can make them only be evaluated once without introducing them as globals.

Example:

```
def _func():
    c0 = np.array([1,2,3])
    c1 = np.array([1,2,3])
    c2 = np.array([1,2,3])
    c3 = np.array([1,2,3])
    def actual_func(x, y, z):
        # do stuff
        # return stuff
    return actual_func

_func_closure = _func()

def func(x, y, z):
    return _func_closure(x, y, z)
```

The last definition is only there to avoid making a global variable out of the function - `func = _func()` works equally well if you don't mind that.

This can probably be written more elegantly, but it illustrates the idea, which is essentially "add a level of indirection".

Disclaimer: I have absolutely no idea about whether this has any better performance.

(If you're interested in "tricks" like this, there's plenty in any decent book on Lisp.)

Answer (score 4):

The scope of `c0`, `c1`, etc. is limited to `func` method only. So, **each time you call the function these variables will be initialized**.

If you want them to be initialized only once and then use it in `func` each time you call, you can define it outside the `func` method:

```
import numpy as np

c0 = np.array([1,2,3])
c1 = np.array([1,2,3])
c2 = np.array([1,2,3])
c3 = np.array([1,2,3])

def func(x,y,z):

    #do stuff with variables x,y,z
    #return stuff
```

Comment: The point is that they are constants. They only way to obtain the nature of constants in the function is to declare them outside the function?